# Check wav file exists in Matlab folder

Tags: matlab

I need to check whether a wav file in Matlab work folder exists ou not. If it does, I need to load the file into a variable (file in my case), i use this code but it doesn't work.

```
      if strcmp(file,'\n')==0
          file='test.wav';           
      elseif findstr(file,'.')==''
          file=strcat(file,'.wav');
      end
      [TestWave,Fs] = audioread(file);
```

Comment: Where in this code do you think that you are testing if the file exists?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you are trying to find a particular .WAV file, or just any .WAV file...

If you just want to know if a particular file (of any kind) exists, use the **exist()** function. It returns value 2 if a file exits:

```
myFileName = 'test.wav';
myDirectory = 'c:\temp';
filepath = fullfile(myFileName,myDirectory);
if exist(filepath,'file') == 2
    [TestWave,Fs] = audioread(file);
end
```

Otherwise, just search for the files you need using **dir()**:

```
myDirectory = 'c:\temp';
wildcard = '*.wav';

theseFiles = dir(fullfile(myDirectory,wildcard));
for i = 1:length(theseFiles)
    thisFilePath = fullfile(myDirectory,theseFiles(i).name);
    [TestWave,Fs] = audioread(thisFilePath);    % Load this file

    % Do something with the loaded file...
end
```